# Vertical spacing between WKInterfaceGroup

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-watch, wkinterfacegroup

I want to reduce the vertical spacing between two groups so that they nearly overlap each-other. is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can set the 'Spacing' to a value of your liking. It will effect the contents based on the layout type. Choosing a vertical layout will get you the vertical spacing you are after.

[image: XCode Interface Builder Screen]